# background-attachment: fixed not working on Safari

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser, background-attachment, background-size

I've got the following code running on an element that spans 100% of the browser:

```
#section_white {
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-image:url(image_url_here.jpg);
  background-position:100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

What I need to do is to have the image span the entire width of the browser, while remaining fixed (thereby allowing the content to scroll on top of it).

It seems to work on all the browsers except Safari - any ideas what I'm missing?

I've tried setting the element **height** and **min-height** to **100%**, with no joy.

A link to a demo page can be seen here: http://oscarsarc.tinygiantstudios.co.za/adopt/adopt-nationwide/

Comment: What version of safari you are using everything seems perfect in ma safari.

Comment: Hmmm. Odd.

Using 5.1.7 on Win 8.1

Comment: This is version 7.0.6 mac

Comment: Doh. Windows Safari stopped development at 5.1.7. No wonder it looks off.

Comment: Check out ma answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Safari for Windows is no longer supported (how did I miss this?!) and the one I'm using is far too old to be useful. Using OSX / Safari, things look peachy (according to Benjamin)

Comment: Protip: Internet Explorer for Mac was also discontinued. :-P

Answer (score -2):

So this will help since `background-size` is partially supported in your version of safari you should use `prefix` just as below

```
html { 
  background: url(image_url_here.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Try this and let me know any issues.

**[SOURCE LINK](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)**

[**CHECK BROWSER SUPPORT**](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size)

Comment: Still no joy; the browser prefixes only push the bg image down. the fixed and cover images still don't play together nicely.

Comment: Ditto. Thanks for taking the time though. Much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try doctype on the html