# parallax mobile doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

So I am using bootstrap for responsiveness and I created a parallax class. It works fine on my laptop browsers when I resize the screens.

However when I open it on my mobile phone the image is just fixed.

here is the class

```
 .parallax {
        /* The image used */
        background-image: url(......);
        /* Set a specific height */
        min-height: 350px;

        /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;

    }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045364/fixed-body-background-scrolls-with-the-page-on-ios7

Comment: [here is solution in first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972352/background-attachment-fixed-not-working-on-safari)